# Como alinhar texto a direita em uma lista

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer uma alteração em um código que tenho e o que para mim parecia relativamente fácil se tornou uma dificuldade, o que tenho é isso:

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"> <img id="brand-image" alt="ANC Estofados" src="images/anc.png"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="contact-details">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-phone"></i> +51 44 3233-3780</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-mail-2"></i> ancestofados@ancestofados.com.br</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O texto que preciso alinhar a direita são os que estão dentro da `div` `top-bar` onde tenho posicionado uma `ul` `top-bar`.

O css que tenho é esse:

```
.top-bar .contact-details li {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.top-bar .contact-details li a:before {
    position: relative;
    content: "|";
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    top: -1px;
    color: #ddd;
}

.top-bar .contact-details li a:before {
    color: #aaa;
}

.top-bar .contact-details li:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}

.top-bar .contact-details li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 68px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

O que tentei fazer foi alinhar o texto a direita com `text-align: right;` no código acima, mas não surtiu nenhum efeito ao ser publicado.

Se preferirem dar uma olhada no projeto, o link é esse:
[Site](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema não é o alinhamento do texto em si, e sim o posicionamento do elemento `li` dentro da `ul`.

Aplique o código abaixo no elemento `ul`:

```
text-align: right;
```

Assim:

```
.top-bar ul {
    text-align: right;
};
```

Obs.:
Não precisa usar float, o que pode bagunçar seu código.

Comment: Olá @CelsomTrindade, obrigado pela grande ajuda.

Comment: @adventistapr não por isso, amigo. Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcar como aceita ;)

Answer (score 3):

A questão é usar alinhamento à direita num elemento inline-block. Tente usar float right;

```
.top-bar .contact-details li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Olá @RodrigoMello, valeu pela ajuda, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

Desta forma, a ordem dos itens do menu vai inverter.
Proponho uma pequena alteração na sua proposta (aplicar a "lu" em vez de "li")

.top-bar .contact-details ul {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @user3059287, foi de grande ajuda.